# How to add 'prefix' for 'Select' and 'DatePicker' in AntDesign

Tags: reactjs, antd

ant-design has`prefix`attribute for `<Input>` and it make the form fields along with the the icons. However, the `prefix` attribute is not supported in the `<Select>` and `DatePicker`. Please let me know how to add `prefix` so that the form will look consistent.

[image]

Refer to the Gender and Birthday fields. It looks smaller than the rest because of missing `prefix` attribute.

Here is the working example for Input.

```
<Form.Item
                name="last_name"
                label="Last Name"
                rules={[{ message: "Please input your lastname!" }]}>
                <Input
                  prefix={
                    <i className="site-form-item-icon fa-solid fa-user"></i>
                  }
                />
              </Form.Item>
```

Here is the expected feature.

```
<Form.Item
                name="gender"
                label="Gender"
                rules={[{ message: "Please select gender!" }]}>
                <Select placeholder="Select your gender" prefix={
                    <i className="site-form-item-icon fa-solid fa-user"></i>
                  }>
                  <Option key="male">Male</Option>
                  <Option key="female">Female</Option>
                  <Option key="other">Other</Option>
                </Select>
              </Form.Item>
```

Comment: AntD does not support `prefix` prop for `select` element. They claim it would make the select component even more complex than it already is hence a straight-up no for such a feature. There are multiple workarounds such as `Input.Group` or adding an icon next to each select item but hiding it in the dropdown menu. Here is an example: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/intelligent-wildflower-fbo1c?file=%2Findex.js%3A36%2C27-36%2C33

Comment: Perhaps you might find this interesting: https://impact.hashnode.dev/how-to-add-a-prefix-icon-to-ant-design-select-component